# Why doesn't mySQL give an error for "{" when trying to rename a database?

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, rename

I am working with mySQL in NetBeans and I am trying to rename a database. The updated syntax can be found here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-database.html. This is the one I am using.

```
ALTER {DATABASE | NBUSER} DATABASE UPGRADE DATA DIRECTORY NAME;
```

I keep getting this error:
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "{" at line 1, column 7.

Any suggestions to why I am getting this error?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

The syntax provided is to tell you that you can use either of the 2 objects.

So try only

```
ALTER DATABASE UPGRADE DATA DIRECTORY NAME;
```

But from the documentation it seems that you also must specify the database name.

Have a look at their example

```
ALTER DATABASE `#mysql50#a-b-c` UPGRADE DATA DIRECTORY NAME;
```

Comment: I tried that but then it said:Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "DATABASE" at line 1, column 7 and I sent the command ALTER DATABASE '#mysql#database_name' UPGRADE DATA DIRECTORY NAME;

Comment: sorry, I entered '#mysql50#database_name' UPGRADE DATA DIRECTORY NAME;